# Change new line into New Record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have record as shown below:

[image]

Is it possible to turn this record on SQL Server 2008 R2 into table below?

[image]

Picture 1
SiteName type is Varchar and Allocation is Varchar too. Every value has new line, i mean new line is char(13). the value could be '(0.0 - 12.0)' + CHAR(13) + '(15.0 - 18.0)' and so on.

Picture 2
this char(13) is a reference to break every line into new row on field allocation, and every row will inherit their SiteName

The new formatted table will be dump into new table(pic.2), so the original data(pic.1) is just for the reference.

I'm stuck to do this on SQL Server 2008, any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: What is your allocation column type? What language are you using in your app?

Comment: all field are varchar and for language its not yet decided because what we want to do now is just transform the data into new format, so people just parse it into any apps

Comment: You'd certainly be better off storing your data correctly than having to transform it like this.

Comment: @DaleK thanks for the advice, but the problem is the original data is from another party where i have no control :(

Comment: on picture 1,
SiteName type is Varchar and Allocation is Varchar too. Every value has new line, i mean new line is char(13). the value could be '(0.0 - 12.0)' + CHAR(13) + '(15.0 - 18.0)'
 and so on.
on picture 2, this char(13) is a reference to break every line into new row on field allocation, and every row will inherit their SiteName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the data like the example below (you can split by different symbols if `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` is not your new line separators:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [SiteName] NVARCHAR(128)
   ,[Allocation] NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([SiteName], [Allocation])
VALUES 
('a', '1
2')
,('b', '3
4
5')
,('c', '6
7');

WITH DataSource ([SiteName], [Allocations]) AS
(
    SELECT [SiteName]
          ,CAST('<a>' + REPLACE([Allocation], CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '</a><a>') + '</a>' AS XML)
    FROM @DataSource DS
)
SELECT DS.SiteName
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM(T.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(128)')))
FROM DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY  DS.Allocations.nodes('./a') T(c);
```

Comment: thanks @gotqn, i will try to implement to my table now. will be back later